# Test beforeInterceptor in integration test in grails

Tags: testing, grails, interceptor

Is there a way to test this interceptor? It's being ignored in my test.

Code:

```
class BaseDomainController {
    def beforeInterceptor = {
        throw new RuntimeException()
        if(!isAdmin()){
            redirect(controller: 'login', action: 'show')
            return
        }
    }
}

class BaseDomainControllerSpec extends IntegrationSpec{

    BaseDomainController controller = new BaseDomainController()

    def 'some test'(){
        given: 
            controller.index()
        expect:
            thrown(RuntimeException)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this thread http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Controller-interceptors-and-unit-tests-td1326852.html Graeme indicates you have to call the interceptor separately. In our case, since we are using the interceptor to check a token, and it's the same for every action, we used:

```
@Before
void setUp() 
{
    super.setUp();
    controller.params.token = "8bf062eb-ec4e-44ae-8872-23fad8eca2ce"
    if (!controller.beforeInterceptor())
    {
        fail("beforeInterceptor failed");
    }    
}
```

I guess if each unit test specifies different arguments for the interceptor, you'll have to call it separately each time. If don't want to to this, I think you have to use something like the Grail's functional testing, which will go through the entire lifecycle: http://grails.org/plugin/functional-test

Answer (score 1):

Grails documentation states:

> Grails does not invoke interceptors or servlet filters when calling actions during integration testing. You should test interceptors and filters in isolation, using functional testing if necessary.

This applies to unit tests also, your controller actions are unaffected by the defined interceptors.

Given that you have:

```
    def afterInterceptor = [action: this.&interceptAfter, only: ['actionWithAfterInterceptor','someOther']]

    private interceptAfter(model) { model.lastName = "Threepwood" }
```

To test the interceptor you should:

Verify that intercepting is applied to the desired actions

```
void "After interceptor applied to correct actions"() {

    expect: 'Interceptor method is the correct one'
    controller.afterInterceptor.action.method == "interceptAfter"

    and: 'Interceptor is applied to correct action'
    that controller.afterInterceptor.only, contains('actionWithAfterInterceptor','someOther')
}
```

Verify that the interceptor method has the desired effect

```
void "Verify interceptor functionality"() {

    when: 'After interceptor is applied to the model'
    def model = [firstName: "Guybrush"]
    controller.afterInterceptor.action.doCall(model)

    then: 'Model is modified as expected'
    model.firstName == "Guybrush"
    model.lastName == "Threepwood"
}
```

Or if you have no interceptors, verify there isn't any

```
void "Verify there is no before interceptor"() {
    expect: 'There is no before interceptor'
    !controller.hasProperty('beforeInterceptor')
}
```

Those examples were for testing after interceptors but same should apply to before interceptors also.